# How to do NTLM Authentication with Xamarin ModernHttpClient or System.Net.Http.httpClient

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient

I am using this httpClient in a Xamarin application:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
```

My server requires NTLM authentication. I believe I have to do something like  this:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("NTLM",...);
```

But it is unclear to me, how I should replace the "...". The Documentation fo AuthenticationHeaderValue does not say anything.

Is this the correct way? What do I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android/iOS/UWP in a `.NET Standard 1.4` library using `System.Net.Http.httpClient` used in a Xamarin project: (I have not used `ModernHttpClient` yet)

```
// Note: The NTLM domain is important here, otherwise basic auth will be used:
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials, UseDefaultCredentials = false }

var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

`client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization` can be left alone, as the above code will internally generate the authorization header for each request.